# C# remove items in List<T> with mouse click in windows form

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-forms-designer

I'm really sorry to ask, but I'm getting desperate for not finding this after a couple of houres. So I know I can't use a foreach lus with a `element.Remove()` and that I need to use a for lus. But I just can't find a solution because it's a little bit more complicated. I'm making a drag and drop app with logic gates and I put these gates in a `List<T>` namely:

```
private List<Tuple<Point, int>> droppedShapes = new List<Tuple<Point, int>>();
```

I need to remove a gate with a click on the gate when i placed it, this is the method:

```
  private void DeleteSelectedComponent(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (droppedShapes != null)
        {
            foreach (var pair in droppedShapes)
            {
                var location = pair.Item1;

                if (Math.Abs(location.X - e.X) < 25 && Math.Abs(location.Y - e.Y) < 25) //looks at width and height of component
                {
                    droppedShapes.Remove(pair);

                    this.Invalidate();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need that `var location` to know what gate needs to be deleted but I can't put this code in a for lus. (don't mind the very bad code) Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.
Here is the rest of my code if you need extra info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo3
{
public partial class MainProgram : Form
{

    private Graphics screen;
    private Bitmap backBuffer;
    private Point? currentLocation = null;

    private List<Tuple<Point, int>> droppedShapes = new List<Tuple<Point, int>>(); // Use your own Shape-interface in stead of the listbox index

    private List<String> ports = new List<string>();

    private HelpClass helpclass;

    private bool delete = false;

    public MainProgram()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backBuffer = new Bitmap(drawPanel.Width, drawPanel.Height);
        screen = Graphics.FromImage(backBuffer);
        this.currentLocation = new Point(20, 20);

        helpclass = new HelpClass();

        FillBox();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        screen.Clear(Color.Black);

        Pen whitePen = new Pen(Color.White);
        SolidBrush tealBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Teal);
        SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        SolidBrush grayBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

        foreach (var pair in this.droppedShapes)
        {
            var shapeType = pair.Item2; // Reveal your own shape object here
            var location = pair.Item1;

            switch (shapeType) // Reveal your own shape object here
            {
                case 0:
                    screen.DrawRectangle(whitePen, location.X - 10, location.Y - 10, 20, 20);
                    screen.DrawString("&", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)18), whiteBrush, location.X - 11, location.Y - 13);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y + 6, location.X - 10, location.Y + 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y - 6, location.X - 10, location.Y - 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 20, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    screen.DrawRectangle(whitePen, location.X - 10, location.Y - 10, 20, 20);
                    screen.DrawString("1", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)10), whiteBrush, location.X, location.Y - 9);
                    screen.DrawString(">", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)8), whiteBrush, location.X - 8, location.Y - 10);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 1, location.Y + 1, location.X - 5, location.Y + 1);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y + 6, location.X - 10, location.Y + 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y - 6, location.X - 10, location.Y - 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 20, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    screen.DrawRectangle(whitePen, location.X - 10, location.Y - 10, 20, 20);
                    screen.DrawString("1", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)12), whiteBrush, location.X - 7, location.Y - 9);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y, location.X - 10, location.Y);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 20, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 16, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y - 6);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    screen.DrawRectangle(whitePen, location.X - 10, location.Y - 10, 20, 20);
                    screen.DrawString("&", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)18), whiteBrush, location.X - 11, location.Y - 13);

                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y + 6, location.X - 10, location.Y + 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y - 6, location.X - 10, location.Y - 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 20, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 16, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y - 6);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    screen.DrawRectangle(whitePen, location.X - 10, location.Y - 10, 20, 20);
                    screen.DrawString("1", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)10), whiteBrush, location.X, location.Y - 9);
                    screen.DrawString(">", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)8), whiteBrush, location.X - 8, location.Y - 10);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 1, location.Y + 1, location.X - 5, location.Y + 1);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y + 6, location.X - 10, location.Y + 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 20, location.Y - 6, location.X - 10, location.Y - 6);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 20, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y);
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 16, location.Y, location.X + 10, location.Y - 6);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

        }

        for (int i = drawPanel.Left - 5; i < drawPanel.Right + 10 ; i += 5)
        {
            for (int j = drawPanel.Top - 50 ; j < drawPanel.Bottom - 5 ; j += 5)
            {
                screen.FillEllipse(redBrush, i, j, 2, 2);
            }
        }


        // draw current location
        if (currentLocation != null)
        {
            Point p = currentLocation.Value;
            screen.FillEllipse(tealBrush, p.X + 1, p.Y, -4, -4);
        }

        drawPanel.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0); //allows you to draw
    }



    private void DrawPanel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (delete == false)
        {
            if (CheckIfCollision(e))
            {
                droppedShapes.Add(new Tuple<Point, int>(new Point(helpclass.WidthSnap(e.X, drawPanel.Width), helpclass.HeightSnap(e.Y, drawPanel.Height)), (int)ComponentList.SelectedIndex));
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DeleteSelectedComponent(e);
        }

    }

    private void drawPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.currentLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void drawPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.currentLocation = null;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void FillBox()
    {
        AddComponent();
        foreach (string component in ports)
        {
            ComponentList.Items.Add(component);
        }
    }

    private void AddComponent()
    {
        ports.Add("AND - Port");
        ports.Add("OR - Port");
        ports.Add("NOT - Port");
        ports.Add("NAND - Port");
        ports.Add("NOR - Port");
    }


    private bool CheckIfCollision(MouseEventArgs e) //checks if position is already taken
    {
        String message = "";
        foreach (var pair in this.droppedShapes)
        {
            var location = pair.Item1;
            if (Math.Abs(location.X - e.X) < 25 && Math.Abs(location.Y - e.Y) < 25) //looks at width and height of component
            {
                message += "Position is already taken!";
                MessageBox.Show(message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void deleteButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (deleteButton.Checked)
        {
            delete = true;
            //Console.WriteLine("true");

        }
        else
        {
            delete = false;
            //Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }

    private void DeleteSelectedComponent(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (droppedShapes != null)
        {
            foreach (var pair in droppedShapes)
            {
                var location = pair.Item1;

                if (Math.Abs(location.X - e.X) < 25 && Math.Abs(location.Y - e.Y) < 25) //looks at width and height of component
                {
                    droppedShapes.Remove(pair);

                    this.Invalidate();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void restartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        droppedShapes.Clear();
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That "lus" is missing `break;`.  Required because continuing the iterate the list is going to bomb, you modified it.  Removing more than one doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know that too! :D

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe, maybe not. If the OP's intent is to remove all shapes that are within that hit-test (if shapes are allowed to overlap), it would make sense to iterate them all. A loop may not be needed at all, a fancy LINQ statement or predicate would do it in the `.Remove` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ones you need to remove to a new list:

```
private void DeleteSelectedComponent(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (droppedShapes == null)   //Early-exit avoids arrow code, easier to read!
        return;

    var removeList = new List<Tuple<Point, int>>();

    foreach (var pair in droppedShapes)
    {
        var location = pair.Item1;

        if (Math.Abs(location.X - e.X) < 25 && Math.Abs(location.Y - e.Y) < 25) //looks at width and height of component
            removeList.Add(pair);  
    } 

    removeList.ForEach(o => droppedShapes.Remove(o));
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

The issue is that you can't iterate through a list and delete them at the same time. Add them to another list and remove them outside of the for-each.

Comment: THANK YOU! :) yes It didn't work at first but now it does! I Thank you very much sir!